# C# Casting Not Working

Tags: c#, casting

I have these classes, partial listing of the relevant bits.

```
public class IVRTopology {}

public abstract class SANSwitch 
{  public string name { get; set; }
}

public class CiscoSwitch : SANSwitch
{
  public IVRTopology IVRTop = new IVRToplogy()
}

 class SwitchViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public SANSwitch sanswitch {  get;  set;  }
}
```

When I do something like this:

```
SwitchViewModel svm = new SwitchViewModel();
svm.sanswitch = new CiscoSwitch();
IVRTopology topo = svm.sanswitch.IVRTop;
```

the compiler warns me that svm.sanswitch is of type SANSwitch and doesn't have a definition for IVRTop if I try to access IVRTop thusly:

```
IVRTopology topo = (CiscoSwitch)svm.SANSwitch.IVRTop
```

doesn't work either.  I don't want to add a definition for IVRTopology to the abstract class because I will have other subclasses of it that don't use it.  Is there something wrong with the cast? How can I make this work? I want the view model to eventually support different kinds of switches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting is a lower precedence operation than the `.` operator.

Therefore, when you run the following code:

```
IVRTopology topo = (CiscoSwitch)svm.SANSwitch.IVRTop
```

You are effectively running

```
var ivrTop = svm.SANSwitch.IVRTop;
IVRTopology topo = (CiscoSwitch)ivrTop;
```

The easy fix is to use brackets to force the correct resolution:

```
IVRTopology topo = ((CiscoSwitch)svm.SANSwitch).IVRTop
```

Answer (score 2):

You're casting the result of `svm.SANSwitch.IVRTop`, when you actually want to cast `svm.SANSWitch` first like this:

```
((CiscoSwitch) svm.SANSwitch).IVRTop
```

Even better, in C# you have safe casting (since `(CiscoSwitch) svm.SANSwitch` might throw an error if it's of the incorrect type), you can do something fancy like this:

```
(svm.SANSwitch as CiscoSwitch)?.IVRTop
```

First we make a safe cast to `CiscoSwitch`, which might be null, then we Null Propagate `?` and retrieve the value. Null Propagation only works if the resulting value is not null - so everything is pretty safe in this line. Then you might want to check if it succeeded in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.

```
IVRTopology topo = ((CiscoSwitch)svm.SANSwitch).IVRTop;
```